# Is it okay to lock a row for a long period? (days or weeks)

Tags: sql, postgresql

For example, we have the following table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE tasks (
  id UUID,
  name VARCHAR
)
```

Now we want to assign these tasks to a worker, but the worker will need up to 1 month to complete the task.

Is it okay if we get an exclusive lock on the task from the worker and release it on worker failure/completion ?

Creating a separate table tracking workers and assigning workerId to tasks then health checking the workerId with taskId would be another solution.

If there are any tips regarding this, I would love to hear about them, Thanks in advance.

Comment: Locks are how the database manages access to the data.  What you're suggesting is not how I'd use such a lock.  If you need to prevent updates; you could create a before update trigger and check to see if the user making the update is the worker; if not abort the update...  But I can't imagine using database locks this way.

Comment: What do you mean with lock?

Comment: Wow. I would assume a transaction would have to be in progress the whole time? Don't your transactions time out eventually?

Comment: Definitely go with the separate table tracking workers and assignments.  Even if the long-lived locks didn't cause other problems (they would) you would still have no visibility into who has been assigned what if the assignments are not committed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you keep a database lock for such a long time, you have to keep a transaction open for a long time. That is going to hurt your database, because autovacuum won't be able to clean up, and concurrent sessions may get stuck behind the lock.

I recommend that you add another column to the table that indicates if the row is "locked" or not.

Comment: And the database lock won’t survive a loss or closing of the database connection, nor a restart of the database server.